# Second born amplitude for the electron-hydrogen scattering

Tags: scattering, born-oppenheimer-approximation

can someone explain how could they got the result of the second born formula written in equation 2.36 from 2.32
I failed to demonstrate it.
The image from Byron 1973 here the link
[enter link description here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.8.1267)
[image] Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the citation, or a link to the full paper, or at least the referenced Equation 2.30?

Comment: It's also fairly difficult to read the equations in the image at the resolution you provided. If possible please LaTex the relevant equation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry, I hope it's clear now. My problem is how they got the result 2.36 from the general term(2.32), I tried times and times to find it but failed